# Does Windows Server 2012 R2 work with Bootcamp on MacbookPro running Mavericks?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, dual-boot

I am trying to figure out if I can run Windows Server 2012 R2 as a boot camp partition with Mavericks. What drivers should I use? Are there any issues?

Comment: I am not having any luck running it in VirtualBox in El Capitan.